# Arithmetic and Geom. sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find the arithmetic sequence a, b, c, d if (a-2), (b-4), (c-3), (d+2) is a geometric sequence.

I've tried setting up ratios with the terms of the geometric sequence, but I'm not sure how to solve those to get a, b, c, and d.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As $a,b,c,d$ form an arithmetic series, let $k$ denote the increment between consecutive terms, so that $b=a+k$, $c=a+2k$ and $d=a+3k$.

The constant ratio of the geometric series will form the following equalities 
$$\frac{a+k-4}{a-2}=\frac{a+2k-3}{a+k-4}=\frac{a+3k+2}{a+2k-3}$$
After some (slightly tedious) algebraic manipulations we have
$$k^2=3a+4k-10=4a+2k-17\Rightarrow a-2k=7$$
Substituting this into the geometric ratio equalities results (after some simplification) in a quadratic in $k$:-
$$(k-11)(k+1)=0$$
We have two possible solutions $k=-1$ (hence $a=5$) or $k=11$ ($a=29$).

Trying out the first solution results in a violation of the geometric ratio, so the only solution is $k=11$ and $a=29$, leading to $b=40$, $c=51$ and $d=62$ (satisfying the geometric series, which is $27,36,48,64$).